# i want to create a function to roll a set number of dice thru the num variable in pythonic way

Tags: python, list, function, random, numbers

My question is how do i get the list roll to print 6 numbers?

```
import random
from random import *
num = 6

def d6(num):
  for x in range(num):
  roll = randint(1,6)
  print ("", roll)
print("finished you rolled: ",roll)
```

Comment: Can you format this correctly? Your code will not run as it's written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append each roll to an array, and then print the array.

```
import random
from random import *
num = 6

def d6(num):
    rolls = []
    for x in range(num):
            rolls.append(randint(1,6))
    print rolls

>>> d6(5)
[4, 6, 1, 1, 1]
```

`

Comment: this seems closest to my desired output, essentially i wanted this function to return the values to use with character creation etc....

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all in a single list comprehension:

```
import random

def d6(num):
    return [random.randint(1,6) for i in range(num)]

print d6(6)
```

If you want, it's pretty easy to modify this so that you can use n-sided dice:

```
import random

def rolldice(num, sides=6):
    return [random.randint(1,sides) for i in range(num)]

print rolldice(5) # roll 5 six-sided dice
print rolldice(6, 20) # roll 6 20-sided dice
```

If you have a situation where you might throw mixed dice, you could input those as a list:

```
import random

def rolldice(dice):
    return [random.randint(1, die) for die in dice]

print rolldice([6, 6, 20, 100, 20])
# Example output - [5, 1, 9, 84, 13]
```

Comment: what is proper syntax for this line:   return [random.randint(1, die) for die in dice)]

Comment: @GarryHurst I accidentally left in an extra closing parenthesis. It should end with `dice]`, not `dice)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to hazard a guess that you are trying to print the rolls on a line after your message.

```
import random
from random import *
num = 6

def d6(num):
    rolls = []
    for x in range(num):
        rolls.append(randint(1,6))
    return rolls

rolls = d6(6);
print("finished you rolled: ",rolls)
```

Alternatively, you can print space-delimited as follows.

```
print("finished you rolled: " + " ".join(str(x) for x in rolls))
```